# Java - Get first letter of string

Tags: java, android, string, speech-to-text

I am trying to extract the first letters of each word in a sentence the user has spoken into my app. Currently if the user speaks "Hello World 2015" it inserts that into the text field. I wish to split this so if the user speaks "Hello World 2015" only "HW2015" is inserted into the text field.

```
final ArrayList<String> matches = data.getStringArrayListExtra(
                RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);
```

The matches variable is storing the users input in an array.I have looked into using split but not sure exactly how this works.

How would I achieve this?

Thank You

Comment: How are you expecting to be able to tell the difference between words and a number?

Comment: It's unclear what your requirements are as @thatidiotguy pointed out. Also, did you try anything yet? That's great you've looked into split, but there should be *tons* of examples of how to use it that should get you started.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can split a string into an array of string by doing this:

```
String[] result = my_string.split("\\s+");  // This is a regex for matching spaces
```

You could then loop over your array, taking the first character of each string:

```
// The string we'll create
String abbrev = "";

// Loop over the results from the string splitting
for (int i = 0; i < result.length; i++){

    // Grab the first character of this entry
    char c = result[i].charAt(0);

    // If its a number, add the whole number
    if (c >= '0' && c <= '9'){
        abbrev += result[i];
    }

    // If its not a number, just append the character
    else{
        abbrev += c;
    }
}
```

Comment: Once the string has been processed ("HW2015") it no longer contains spaces, per OP; you should remove the `abbrev += " ";` lines.

Comment: @Tyler that works fine but can't put the abbrev into a alert dialog. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

pass this regex and your list into applyRegexToList

it reads:
(get first character) or (any continuous number) or (any character after a space)

```
(^.{0,1})|(\\d+)|((?<=\\s)[a-zA-z])
```

()

```
 public static ArrayList<String> applyRegexToList(ArrayList<String> yourList, String regex){

    ArrayList<String> matches = new ArrayList<String>();

    // Create a Pattern object
    Pattern r = Pattern.compile(regex);

    for (String sentence:yourList) {
        // Now create matcher object.

        Matcher m = r.matcher(sentence);
        String temp = "";

        //while patterns are still being found, concat
        while(m.find())
        {
            temp += m.group(0);
        }
        matches.add(temp);
    }

    return matches;
}
```

Comment: Please try to answer the question in a more readable and complete way, and apply some formatting to your code. It's easy: Use the {} button on the edit form. @BasicCoder is using Java and would probably want to know how you apply this RegEx to an ArrayList<String>.